# Variance of the MLE estimator of a function of bernoulli parameter

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

I have a bernoulli RV $X$ defined as below:

$pr(X=1)=1-(1-p)^{k}$

$pr(X=0)=(1-p)^{k}$

Assume I have $N$ independent observations on the RV $X$. I am interested in finding the MLE estimator of $k$ and its variance.

My attempt:
let $\mu=1-(1-p)^{k}$ . Then, $\hat{\mu}=\frac{\sum{x_i}}{N}$. Thus, $\hat{k}=\frac{log(1-\frac{\sum{x_i}}{N})}{log(1-p)}$.
But, I am not sure what is the best approach to find the variance of $\hat{k}$.Can someone guide me through those steps?

Comment: You can get the proper font and spacing for $\log$ using `\log`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: @joriki, I considered the likelihood fcn and the estimator of $\mu$ is based on that. Then , I used the invariance property to derive estimator for $k$.  I do not want to constrain k as integers.

Comment: I see. I'll delete my comment. But I'd suggest not to use $k$ for a non-integer variable in an exponent.